Как добавить свой стиль редактирования текста в меню Gutenberg?
Подскажите, как добавить свой стиль редактирования текста в меню Gutenberg ? Где найти инфу?
Например я хочу сделать свой стиль редактирования текста, чтобы к тексту добавлялся класс допустим.
скрин


Ничего не понятно... Классы и id можно прописывать блокам без танцев с бубнами. Из коробки. Или в чём вопрос? О чем скрин панели дефлотного абзаца?

Нужно в выделенную панель редактирования текста добавить свой кастомный тип редактирования текста, а не к целому блоку класс задавать.

Вроде как то что Вам нужно, можно сделать через данный фильтр, если я Вас верно понял

Какой ещё "тип редактирования"? Научись излагать мысли так, чтобы тебя понимали. См https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6688/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE-wordpress

@Simon Спасибо, то что нужно!


В Гутенберге уже есть возможнасть назначать id или class каким-то элементам. Для этого ничего програмировать не надо.

Нет, вы можете задать класс только целому блоку, а не куску текста. Вопрос в том, чтобы создать новый тип редактирования в этом меню.
